# How to fix disappearing hoverable Box with HTML-Select-Input (in Firefox)

Tags: html, css, firefox, hover, html-select

I'm trying to fix an issue with a hoverable span in html. Inside the span element is a html-select option. When I try to select something, the hoverable span disappears.

This issue only occurs in Firefox. In Chrome I don't have this issue.

HTML Part:

```html
<span class="over">
   <i class="fa fa-cogs edit"></i>
 <div>
      <form method="post" accept-charset="utf-8" action="/edit">
         <div class="input select">
            <label for="select-id">Select</label>
            <select name="select_id" id="select-id">
               <option value="">-- select --</option>
               <option value="1">A</option>
               <option value="2">B</option>
               <option value="3">C</option>

            </select>
         </div>
      </form>
   </div>
</span>
```

SCSS Part:

```css
.over{
        margin-right: 0.5em;
        &>i{
            color: #bbbbbb;
            padding: 2px;
        }
        &>a{
            padding: 2px;
            display: none;
            &:hover{
                color: #000;
            }
        }

        &>div{
            display: none;
            position: absolute;
            border: 1px solid #ccc;
            margin: 6px 0 0 -20px;
            padding: 2px;
            background: white;
            border-radius: 4px;
            min-width: 140px;
            z-index: 100;
            text-align: left;

            input, select{
                padding: 0 5px;
                line-height: 1.5em;
                width: auto;
                display: inline-block;
            }
            label{
                margin: -4px 4px;
                display: inline-block;
            }
        }

        &:hover{
            border: 1px solid;
            border-radius: 4px;
            &>i{
                color: #000;
            }
            &>a{
                display: inherit;
            }

            &>div{
                display: inline-block;
            }
        }
    }


}
```

In Chrome I can hover over the span item and select a option from the select-element. Even if I leave the hoverable area.

In Firefox I can also hover over the div, but as soon as I leave the hoverable area, the box disappears and I cannot select an Item.

Comment: [similar Issue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53534621/hover-div-in-select-option-not-working-firefox)

Answer (score 0):

Problem seems to be fixed in Firefox now.